# Play change Language dynamallicy

Tags: java, playframework

Fairly new to Play trying to change the language dynamically.

**route**

```
GET     /language/:lang             controllers.Index.setLanguage(lang: String)
```

**Tried so far** *(but none of them work)*

```
Lang.apply(language);
Lang.change(language);    // <-- doesn't even compile
Lang.apply(language);
ctx().changeLang(language);
```

**view**

```
@import play.i18n.Messages
...
@Messages.get("message")
@messages.at("message")
...
```

Both not working..

**application.config**

[image]

**messages**

[image]

**Method** *with some logging*

```
public Result setLanguage(String language) {
  Http.Context context = Http.Context.current();
  String langFromHttpContext = context.lang().language();
  String langFromCtx = ctx().lang().language();
  String playLangCookieVal = request().cookies().get("PLAY_LANG").value();
  boolean changed = ctx().changeLang(language);

  Logger.info("Request param: " + language);
  Logger.info("Http context language: " + langFromHttpContext);
  Logger.info("ctx language: " + langFromHttpContext);
  Logger.info("PLAY_LANG cookie value: " + langFromCtx);
  Logger.info("Changed: " + changed);
  return ok(index.render("Index"));
}
```

**Result**

```
application - Request param: en
application - Http context language: nl
application - ctx language: nl
application - PLAY_LANG cookie value: nl
application - Changed: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the `application.langs="nl"` from the configuration. It's deprecated and replaced by the `play.i18n.langs`.

You must leave only `play.i18n.langs=["en","nl"]`

You code does not work because Play reads the `application.langs="nl"` and ignore `play.i18n.langs=["en","nl"]` (because langs already read from the `application.langs`), so it suggest your application use only "nl" language and, of course could not set it to "en", so `ctx().changeLang(language)` method return `false`

Comment: Wow this did the job. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ctx().changeLang(language);
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I don;t get it. Nothing seems to work :')

Comment: Which play version are you on ?

Comment: Currently on 2.5.8

Comment: Could you do Logger.info("language: {}", language); in your method? Make sure that the files in conf/messages got the same name like the language string form request. For example: conf/message.en should exist and the language string from request should be "en".

Comment: Do you mean the language as the parameter of my method or ctx().lang().language()?

Comment: Yes, we need to check if the string is the same like one of the messages files in conf/

Comment: So I just check one of my projects, the only difference I could find was that I did a redirect instead of an ok, maybe you could also try that.

Comment: Seriously? Because this doesn't work either so I guess it on my pc / browser settings?

Comment: I could post my solution if you want.

Comment: Yeah that would be great